# jQuery .sortable + receive Event: get the position of the inserted element

Tags: jquery, jquery-ui-sortable

I've got a jQuery sortable element and another draggable element. 
With the sortable receive event i get the new inserted object and start an ajax query to write it in database. 
But it would be nice to get the right position of the new element, too. When i fire sortable("serialize") on receive event, the new element is not in the string. how can i find out the position of the inserted element?

---

Draggable:

```
<div id="docP1" class="docPopC">';
    for($x = 10; $x<30; $x++){
        if($block_ele[$x])
            echo '<p id="b_'.$x.'" class="doc_inhalt_popup">'.$block_ele[$x].'</p>';
    }
echo '
</div>
```

Sortable:

```
<div id="aktiv"><input type="hidden" value="xx" /></div>
```

jQuery:

```
$("#aktiv").sortable({
connectWith: '#aktiv',
forcePlaceholderSize: true,
items: 'div.block',
receive: function(event, ui){
    var nblock = ui.item.attr("id").split("_");

    $.get('inc_dokumente.php', {
        index : 'n256',
        aktiv : $("#aktiv input:first").val(),
        id : rel,
        block: nblock[1]
    }, function(data){ 
        load_bloecke();
    });
},
update: function(event, ui){ 
    $.get('inc_dokumente.php', {
        index : 'n257',
        aktiv : $("#aktiv input:first").val(),
        id : rel,
        sort: $("#aktiv").sortable("serialize")
    }, function(data){
        if(data) alert(data);
        load_bloecke();
    });
}
});

$(".docPopC p").draggable({
    connectToSortable: '#aktiv',
    helper: 'clone',
    revert: 'invalid',
    zIndex: 9999999,
    appendTo: 'body'
});
```

Comment: Please post some code. Without seeing it, I would guess the ID of the element dropped into the sortable area does not match the required `setname_number` format.

Answer (score 0):

The problem is this option when declaring `#aktiv` as sortable

```
items: 'div.block'
```

With this you are saying that only divs with class block should be concidered sortable inside #aktiv, so when you do `$("#aktiv").sortable("serialize")`, jQuery doesn't evaluate the item you dropped into it, since it is a `p` element. If this is the case, then your newly dropped items will also not be sortable with the other elements (the `div.block`s), so you are fixing several problems)

Possible solutions:

- Make #aktiv consider the `p` element a sortable (`items: 'div.block, p.doc_inhalt_popup`)
- Make the `p` elements you drag into `divs` with class `block`
  - (You can skip giving the draggable class block in your HTML and instead add it with jQuery when you receive the item)